# How can I export my Tomboy notes into Evernote?

Tags: tomboy, evernote, gnote

I want to export my Tomboy notes to the Evernote web service, I have seen [this web site](http://tb2en.selfip.com/) but I don't want to send my Tomboy notes to an untrusted site where they may be put to unknown use.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic process seems to be export your Tomboy notes to html: *Tools* > *Export*

Then use email to send the files into your Evernote account. Instructions for using email to import notes are [here in this Evernote support article](http://evernote.com/contact/support/kb/#!/article/23480523).

The notes themselves are stored as individual XML files in `~/.local/share/tomboy`, so it's possible to convert them to whatever form you need through your own scripts if the *Export* doesn't provide exactly you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think its the most reasonable solution that doesn't require writing an app.  The export to html was buggy and I had to pipe through html2text then to mail as well as various other small problems.

Comment: There is a plugin that allows you to export directly to txt.  I found it to be better than html2text when handling all those special characters.  http://www.robpvn.net/plaintext-export/

Answer (score 4):

Use Tomboy2Evernote exporter: https://github.com/rPawel/Tomboy2Evernote

Exports notes with links, colours & formatting straight to *.enex format file.

```
python Tomboy2Evernote.py -i ~/.local/share/tomboy -o ~/Desktop
```

Once you have the exported notes, import them into Evernote:

> File > Import > Evernote Export Files

Comment: Did you use the web app or one of the desktop apps to import the enex file?

Comment: Hi @testerab, I used the latest Windows client available running on Ubuntu 14.04 and Wine.

Comment: Great - thanks @rPawel! I'll try Wine then, I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to find out how to import with web app/Everpad.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind all of your notes on one page (items searchable by hyperlink) you can try this.

1. Copy the following code into a text editor, save as `script.py` and run it in the folder where the Tomboy notes are kept. (Typically `.local/share/tomboy/` in Linux). 
   At the command line, run `python script.py`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   #
   #   This script creates a tomboy note containing link to each other note
   #   so one can easily export all the notes to an HTML file
   #
   #   author:Pedro
   #
   #   Check out lamehacks.net for more lame scripts and stuff

   import dbus, time

   note_title = "Note Index"

   # Get the D-Bus session bus
   bus = dbus.SessionBus()

   # Access the Tomboy D-Bus object
   obj = bus.get_object("org.gnome.Tomboy","/org/gnome/Tomboy/RemoteControl")

   # Access the Tomboy remote control interface
   tomboy = dbus.Interface(obj, "org.gnome.Tomboy.RemoteControl")

   notes_links = ""

   for note in tomboy.ListAllNotes():
   notes_links += tomboy.GetNoteTitle(note) + " \n"

   uri = tomboy.FindNote(note_title)
   if uri == "":
   uri = tomboy.CreateNamedNote(note_title)

   tomboy.SetNoteContents(uri, note_title + "\n\n" + notes_links)
   tomboy.DisplayNote(uri)
   ```

   This will create an empty Tomboy note.
2. Then run this code at the command line, in the same folder where your Tomboy notes are stored:

   ```
   for i in *.note; do
   xpath -q -e '/note/title' $i;
   done \ sed -r 's%^<title>(.*)</title>%\1%g'
   ```

This will generate a list of titles. Copy and Paste those into the blank Tomboy
note created by the python script. Then export this note as a single HTML file. Send this file as an email attachment to your Evernote account.

---

[Code taken from Lamehacks Blog](http://lamehacks.net/blog/archive-tomboy-notes/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python script that simply parses `.note` files from the Tomboy dir and convertes them to `.enex` files, which can then be imported into Evernote via a desktop app:

https://gist.github.com/scribu/7442170

Answer (score 0):

In the nixnote/nevernote package (a linux client for evernote), there is a contributed package called TomboyExporter (see TomboyExporter.tar.gz at http://sourceforge.net/projects/nevernote/files/Current/).

I found it to be poorly documented, but once I figured out how to run it, it worked very well, with the exception of two issues: (1) hyperlinks are converted to plaintext (but underlined), (2) most underlined text (except when surrounded in italics, for example) is just lost, due to a bug. Otherwise, it does a good job at keeping formatting when possible, and it will also organize your notes into notebooks, keeping the same organizational structure you had in Tomboy (also preserves last-modified dates, etc.). It doesn't keep links to other notes, but that's asking a lot.

To use it, extract the .tar.gz package, then go to the src/ directory. Run like:
`java Exporter [desired output directory] ~/.local/share/tomboy/*note`
It creates several .nnex file, one per notebook (so each file contains many notes). Then just import these from evernote.